# jquery binding to a form submit

Tags: jquery

I'm doing the following:

```
    // Post to the server
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $("form.edit_item").attr("action"),
        data: $("form.edit_item").serialize(),
        success: function(e) {
        }
    });


$(".edit_item")
    .bind('ajax:loading', function() {
        alert('go');
    })
    .bind('ajax:success', function(data, status, xhr) {
        alert('going');
    })
});
```

On the form:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/xxxxx/18" class="edit_item" id="edit_item_31" method="post"><div
```

While the form posting works fine.the ajax binds are not working. Suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: The last `});` in your code has no opening `({`

Comment: I'm not familiar with the events you are trying to bind, are these triggered somewhere within code not posted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) options, add a `beforeSend` handler:

```
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: $("form.edit_item").attr("action"),
    data: $("form.edit_item").serialize(),
    beforeSend: function() {
        alert('go');
    },
    success: function(e) {
        alert('going');
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure these are the two you want, the first is for all request batches collectively, the second would fire per-request, perhaps `.ajaxSend()` instead of `.ajaxStart()`?

Comment: @Nick, I think you're right - I'll change it to `.ajaxSend()`.

Comment: @Jacob - It's also worth noting that that's not the signature for `ajaxSuccess` :)

Comment: ok turns out that doesn't work. It's catching AJAX calls for other items on the page.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind to the events that *do* fire, [`ajaxSend`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/) and [`ajaxSuccess`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/), like this:

```
$(".edit_item").bind({
  ajaxSend: function() {
    alert('go');
  },
  ajaxSuccess: function() {
    alert('going');
  }
});
```

These fire *per request* is for you want alerts when a batch starts/finishes, replace `ajaxSend` with [`ajaxStart`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) and `ajaxSuccess` with [`ajaxStop`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/).

Comment: Thanks Nick, same issue. The page is running these items for all AJAX events on the page. Issue being seen is the jquery DIALOG is triggering this bind?

Comment: @AnApprentice - right, these are global handlers...if you want them for just that `$.ajax()` call you should use the `beforeSend` handler (or just run your code before `$.ajax()` and the `success` handler.

Comment: ahh shot. If these are global why would they be binded to a form? very confusing no?

Comment: @AnApprentice - Oh they can be binded to anything, you can view the full global list here: http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/ I do see how they're counter-intuitive compared to other events though :)  Sounds like you just want to call your code in your `$.ajax()` handlers locally.